# Cancel form closing from some event

Tags: c#, .net, savefiledialog, formclosing

I want my *formClosing* event to *cancel* its closing operation if the *SaveFileDialog*, in my *SaveAs* Click event, is *Cancel*

```
void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Close ();
}

void form1_FormClosing (object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
    if (isContentChanged) 
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show ("Do you want to save [ "+this.Text+"] ?", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes) 
        {
            saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click (sender, e);
        } 
        else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) 
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
}


private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog ();
    sfd.Filter = "Drawing Files | *.drg";
    DialogResult result = sfd.ShowDialog ();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
        SaveFile (sfd.FileName);
        isContentChanged = false;
    } 
    else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) 
    {
        // NEED TO CANCEL FORM CLOSING HERE   
    }
}
```

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: you can use a `return;` to cancel the event.

Comment: @FarhanAnam The form will be closed because I'm not cancelling (e.Cancel = true in formclosing event) the form closing. Is it possible to cancel it in this event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   ...

   if (result == DialogResult.OK) 
   {
       ...         
   } 
   else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) 
   {  
       ((FormClosingEventArgs) e).Cancel = true; 
   }
}
```

Comment: It worked :) . But didn't get whats happening here. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @NaveenKumarV...Well in the button click you can't set the `e.Cancel` to `true` so you should cast `e` to `FormClosingEventArgs` so that you can access to `Cancel` property.

Comment: @NaveenKumarV...plus to my previous comment:`FormClosingEventArgs` is derived from `CancelEventArgs` and it derived from `EventArgs`.

Comment: @NaveenKumarV When you call `saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click` from `form1_Closing` you are passing the same `FormClosingEventArgs` as an argument. The method `saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click` receives it disguised as an `EventArgs` (For further reference, see [Polymorphism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173152(v=vs.100).aspx)). The problem is that the type `EventArgs` does not have a property `Cancel` so it's no use  to you at all. Downcasting it to `FormClosingEventArgs` will do the job.

Comment: @NaveenKumarV Please note that if the argument `e` is not a disguised `FormClosingEventArgs` the above code will throw a casting exception.

Comment: Thank you guys :) Understood!. :)

Comment: but I am Getting Invalid Cast exception, what can be the problem?